# Python: Erase all the strings except the information between > < in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, str-replace

I need to erase all the content of the cell, except the information contained between > <

I have a dataframe with 100 * 15, that look like something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['irus 1/3 km >A001< absc ','#$ jiadhf 3 >A002<', '#AB >A003<'], columns=['AFF'])
```

df

```
    AFF
0   irus 1/3 km >A001< absc
1   #$ jiadhf 3 >A002<
2   #AB >A003<
```

I need to get a result like this:

```
    AFF
0   A001
1   A002
2   A003
```

I found that I need to use a command similar to this `re.sub('[^>]+>', '', y)`, but I've been trying several attempts and I can get exactly the info I need.

Can somebody give me a hand?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a *capturing group*:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(['irus 1/3 km >A001< absc ','#$ jiadhf 3 >A002<', '#AB >A003<'], columns=['AFF'])

In [3]: df['AFF'] = df['AFF'].str.extract(r">([A-Z0-9]+)<")

In [4]: print(df)
    AFF
0  A001
1  A002
2  A003
```

Comment: that works well... but when I'm trying to do it for the whole df = df.str.extract(r">([A-Z0-9]+)<"), I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: @PAstudilloE oaky, correct me if I am wrong, you'd like to apply this regex to multiple columns? How many columns do you have? Thanks.

Comment: yes... I need to apply that to 80 different columns.

Comment: @PAstudilloE okay, you could shortcut it to using `.applymap()`. Something along `df.applymap(lambda x: re.search(r">([A-Z0-9]+)<", x).group(1))`. It would though may be a good idea to pre-compile the regex and add some error-handling.

Comment: just test it...  and I'm getting this error. ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'", 'occurred at index Aff_0'). Any clue? I'll try again pre-compiling the regex

Comment: @PAstudilloE ah, I've assumed only upper case and digits, you could adjust your regex to `r">(\w+)<"` - allowing all alphanumerics and an underscore.

Comment: tks!... but I'm still getting the same error. There's an issue with the attribute 'group'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185175/discussion-between-alecxe-and-pastudilloe).